# HTML5 - Anchor separate from base link

Tags: html

I've been practising some HTML5 as of recent, and come to a halt. I've added an anchor to a part of the code, but when I try to link to it, the link goes straight to the base link. Is there anyway to get past this?

This is the snippet of the code:

```
<head>
<base href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" target="_blank" />
</head>
<body>
(...)
Link to anchor: <a href="#link">Link!</a>

(...)

<a name="link">Welcome!</a>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this the point of the `<base>` tag?

Comment: Why are you using the BASE element?

Comment: Other pieces of code are relative links. I use the base-tag to pose as the base portion. Shouldn't there be a way to isolate the base to a specific section, rather than have it in <head> - thus applying it to everything?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<span id="link">Welcome!</span>
```

The [`name` attribute is for form elements](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fe-name) in HTML5.

Comment: Tried it, but to no avail. The problem is most likely between the all-encompassing base and the link to the anchor, but I haven't got a clue how to somehow make them work together.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<base href="http://en.wikipedia.org/" target="_blank" />
</head>
<body>
(...)
Link to anchor: <a href="wiki/">Link!</a>

(...)

<a name="link">Welcome!</a>
</body>
```